# Positioning text in td cell

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="font-size:7pt; font-color:red; font-weight: bold;">
        LET OP: SPECIFICEER HET ATRIKEL ZO GEDETAILLEERD MOGELIJK
    </td>
</tr>
```

But the text doesn't go nice above the textarea box..

See: https://jsfiddle.net/jvdyx0hc/

I want it get the text of LET OP starting on the left side and above the textareabox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried this way

```html
<td colspan="3" style="font-size:7pt; font-color:red; font-weight: bold;padding-left:6%;">LET OP: SPECIFICEER HET ATRIKEL ZO GEDETAILLEERD MOGELIJK</td>
```

here is the jsfiddle

[Demo work code](https://jsfiddle.net/jvdyx0hc/2/)

I am not sure about this but i tried this and worked in both browsers

please check updated fiddle

[Check out in Mozila firefox](https://jsfiddle.net/jvdyx0hc/7/)

Comment: works but in firefox the there is a difference in positioning, how to fix this?

Comment: @bboni after your return i thoroughly tried to find your solution here i am updating that please look at out

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<td colspan="3" style="font-size: 7pt; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 15px;">LET OP: SPECIFICEER HET ATRIKEL ZO GEDETAILLEERD MOGELIJK</td>
```

Comment: works but in firefox the there is a difference in positioning, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your text

```
LET OP: SPECIFICEER HET ATRIKEL ZO GEDETAILLEERD MOGELIJK
```

with:

```
<span style="margin-left: -90px;">LET OP: SPECIFICEER HET ATRIKEL ZO GEDETAILLEERD MOGELIJK</span>
```

You could also replace your tablecell with:

```
<td colspan="3" style="font-size:7pt; font-color:red; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 30px">LET OP: SPECIFICEER HET ATRIKEL ZO GEDETAILLEERD MOGELIJK</td>
```

Sidenote: I'd recommend doing your styling in a stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, try the following:

```
<td colspan="4" style="font-size:7pt; font-color:red; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 82px;">LET OP: SPECIFICEER HET ATRIKEL ZO GEDETAILLEERD MOGELIJK</td>
```

This isn't going to work if you're looking to have the table columns responsive and scale according to screen width. If you're doing that, you're going to want to use 'vw' instead of 'px'.

I would recommend NOT using inline styles like this. If you're looking for a much cleaner way to do this and have the option to use an external style sheet, apply a class to the  element and put the styles in the stylesheet.

HTML

```
<td colspan="4" class="descriptionText">LET OP: SPECIFICEER HET ATRIKEL ZO GEDETAILLEERD MOGELIJK</td>
```

CSS

```
.descriptionText{
    font-size: 7pt;
    font-color:red; 
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 82px;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: works but in firefox the there is a difference in positioning, how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference in positioning. With padding-left: 82px, it is sitting in the same position for both FF and Chrome for me.